# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Too many open files)

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

all! I am writing a java program which is operates with Graphs. The code needs to do some stuff with several graphs. It worked fine, but now, each time when I start the program it stops after exactly 15 execution of the method which process with the graphs one by one. After that, I receive this error on the following line in 'CreateAllVertexCritical' method:

```
    FileWriter fr=new FileWriter(filename, true);
```

One of the most useful links I found is this one(with almost the same problem): 
https://forums.oracle.com/message/8642300
However, I cannot fix the bug. I close all the Streams that I create[please, correct me If I am not right]. I also tried to increase the UBUNTU limit for number of open files, but it didn't help.
Here are the two methods that I call within the main method:

```
 public synchronized static void CreateAllVertexCritical(File f, int nVertices)      throws     IOException {
    isReady=false;
    String s = f.getParent();
    String name = f.getName();
    File newDir = new File(s + "/Reduce" + name);
    newDir.mkdir();

    Path path = Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath());
    InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(path);
    BufferedReader reader
            = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line;
    line = reader.readLine();
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(line);
    m.find();
    m.find();
    String s1 = m.group(2);
    int edgeBr = Integer.parseInt(s1);
    //if (edgeBr<54) return;
    int newEdgeBr = edgeBr - 1;
    //System.out.println(newEdgeBr);
    String[] lastEdges = new String[edgeBr];

    String filename = newDir.getPath() + "/1";
    //File temp = new File(filename);
    // System.out.println(temp.exists());
    //System.out.println(filename);
    FileWriter fr1=new FileWriter(filename, true);
    pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(fr1));
    //System.out.println("p edge " + nVertices + " " + newEdgeBr + "\n");
    pw.print(new String("p edge " + nVertices + " " + newEdgeBr + "\n"));

    line = reader.readLine();
    lastEdges[0] = line;
    for (int l = 2; l <= edgeBr; l++) {
        line = reader.readLine();
        pw.print(line + "\n");
    }
    pw.flush();
    fr1.close();
    for (int j = 2; j <= edgeBr; j++) {
        reader
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Files.newInputStream(path)));
        line = reader.readLine();
        filename = s + "/Reduce" + name + "/" + j;
        FileWriter fr=new FileWriter(filename, true);
        pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(fr));
        pw.print(new String("p edge " + nVertices + " " + newEdgeBr + "\n"));
        for (int l = 1; l < j; l++) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            pw.print(line + "\n");
        }
        line = reader.readLine();
        lastEdges[j - 1] = line;
        for (int l = j + 1; l <= edgeBr; l++) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            pw.print(line + "\n");
        }
        pw.flush();
        fr.close();
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= edgeBr; j++) {
        try {
            Process psmallk = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/user/Desktop/SmallkSrc/smallk " + s + "/Reduce" + name + "/" + j + " 3 6");
            psmallk.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        File normalfile = new File(s + "/Reduce" + name + "/" + j);
        File resfile = new File(s + "/Reduce" + name + "/" + j + ".res");
        if (normalfile.exists() && (resfile.exists())) {
            normalfile.delete();
            resfile.delete();

        } else {
            Path dirPath = Paths.get("/media/user/1898016F98014CA6/F725/Reduce/ForTest14");
            File dirFile = dirPath.toFile();
            int count = dirFile.listFiles(filter).length;
            count++;
            Path tempPath = Paths.get("/media/user/1898016F98014CA6/F725/Reduce/ForTest14/" + count);
            Files.copy(normalfile.toPath(), tempPath);
            //sSystem.out.println(lastEdges[j-1]);
            PrintWriter pwinfo = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pinfo, true)));
            pwinfo.print(count + " :" + lastEdges[j - 1] + "\n");
            pwinfo.flush();
            //CreateAllVertexCritical(normalfile, nVertices);

        }



    }
    isReady=true;

}

public static void CreateAllVertexCriticalRecursive(File f, int n) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //if(f.isDirectory()==true) return;
    Path path = Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath());
    InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(path);
    BufferedReader reader
            = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line;
    line = reader.readLine();
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(line);
    m.find();
    m.find();
    String s1 = m.group(2);
    int edgeBr = Integer.parseInt(s1);

   CreateAllVertexCritical(f, n);
    while(isReady==false){TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(100);}
    String s = f.getParent();
    String name = f.getName();
    File newDir = new File(s + "/Reduce" + name);

    File[] fileArr = newDir.listFiles(filter);
    int brFiles = fileArr.length;
    System.out.println(brFiles);
    if (brFiles>4) System.out.println(newDir.getAbsolutePath() +": "+ brFiles);

    if (brFiles > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < brFiles; i++) {
            //System.out.println("Fail "+ i+" "+ fileArr[i].getName());
            CreateAllVertexCriticalRecursive(fileArr[i], n);
        }
    }

}
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    for(int u=120;u<9241;u++){ //1936 do 2000 missed
        //if (u%3==0) System.gc(); 
        System.out.println(u);
        CreateAllVertexCriticalRecursive(new File("/media/user/1898016F98014CA6/F725/Temp/"+u), 14);
    }
```

Comment: I see only two `close()` calls and lots of new readers being created in your code. You need to refactor this and make sure you close any readers you open. (Why do you need to create so many new readers?).

Comment: Thanks, Jesper.
It was obvious and for now it works!

Comment: For all interested, I needed to close the STDERR, STDIN, and STDOUT streams of the processes I created.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor all of this code to manage all Stream / Reader / Writer objects using a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block.